# Plot subscribers using start and end dates in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I wish to plot the frequency of subscribers over time using start and end date.

I have a method that creates a row for each day per subscriber, then calculates the frequency per day, then plots the frequency by day.

This works fine for small data but does not scale to large subscriber numbers because the rows per customer step is too big.

Is there an efficient method? Many thanks for any help.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

# create dummy dataset
subscribers <- data.frame(id = seq(1:10),
  start = sample(seq(as.Date('2016/01/01'), as.Date('2016/06/01'), by="day"), 10), 
  end   = sample(seq(as.Date('2017/01/01'), as.Date('2017/06/01'), by="day"), 10))

# creates a row for each day per user - OK for small datasets, but not scalable
date_map <- Map(seq, subscribers$start, subscribers$end, by = "day")
date_rows <- data.frame(
  org     = rep.int(subscribers$id,  vapply(date_map, length, 1L)), 
  date    = do.call(c, date_map))

# finds the frequency of users for each day
date_rows %>%
  group_by(date) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(users = n()) -> plot_data

ggplot(data = plot_data,
       aes(x = date, y = users)) +
  geom_line(size = 1.2,alpha = .6)
```

[image: Line plot of subscribers over time]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How's this?

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- subscribers %>%
  gather(key, value, start, end) %>%
  mutate(key = ifelse(key == "start",1,-1)) %>%
  arrange(value)

df$cum <- cumsum(df$key)  

ggplot(data = df,
       aes(x = value, y = cum)) +
  geom_step()
```

Comment: Awesome, many thanks. I was unsure how it was working, but I think I understand it now. It certainly executes on a very large dataset.